# How can I set up an SSL configuration in Namecheap for Angular deployed on GitHub Pages and Django deployed on App Engine

Tags: django, angular, google-app-engine, ssl, https

I am deploying my system, Angular frontend using GitHub and the whole backend in the Google Cloud Platform - App Engine, SQL, Elasticsearch etc. Https seems to be working properly between website and the client as I have checked in the GitHub settings `Enforce HTTPS`. However I am not sure whether I do a correct configuration between Angular app and my Django API which is deployed in the App Engine. Can anyone take a look at the configuration and confirm that everything is done correctly? I would like to do everything as safely as possible. User portal should be accessible from `example.com` and `www.example.com` and the Django API on App Engine from `api.example.com` and `www.api.example.com`. Besides, maybe you have any additional safety tips or advices on what else I could do to increase protection?

Namecheap:

[image]

Google App Engine:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE with the configuration of backend and frontend deployed on Google App Engine**

[image]
[image]
[image]

dispatch.yaml:

```
dispatch:

  - url: "api.example.com/"
    service: backend-service

  - url: "www.api.example.com/"
    service: backend-service

  - url: "api.example.com/*"
    service: backend-service

  - url: "www.api.example.com/*"
    service: backend-service

  - url: "*/*"
    service: frontend-service
```

Comment: Your configuration looks fine but, I don't understand why `www` and naked domain are registered on custom domains for app engine, according your description this the frontend will work with Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine but, I don't understand why `www` and naked domain are registered on custom domains for app engine, according your description the frontend will work with Github.

Also the `*` in the Name cheap records  is not great idea, you can change this to only for the app engine domains `www.api` and `api`

Other security recommendation is to enable [CORS](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/) on your django application, to prevent that unauthorized domains call your api.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have just noticed your message and I really appreciate it. You are right, the site was set up on GitHub and uses `https`, but I thought the communication between Angular's frontend and my API in App Engine should be SSL encrypted anyway. I send passwords, logins and other confidential information there. I understand that if I have set up `https`, then communication between API in App Engine and `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` based on SSL is unnecessary? Could you explain it to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @John Smith You are right, SSL it is necessary and mandatory, but if your website (www.domain.com and domain.com) is not hosted on app engine these are not necessary, but having your certificate on App engine will not affects you.

[CORS](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/) is the only recommendation at this time.

Comment: I have updated my question with new configuration. Can you take a look? Since the SSL set up for `example.com` and `www.example.com` do not negatively affect the communication, can they stay in such configuration or they must be removed?

Comment: Now looks better, and yes if your sites are working properly you can keep your configuration.

Comment: Finally I decided that the best option will be to deploy also the Angular frontend on Google App Engine because I have everything configured like CI/CD pipeline, cloud build, secret manager etc. Sorry for the inconvenience, but could you please check my updated configuration again? Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks very well, also you need to configure the [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/dispatch-yaml) to link correctly your subdomains with your app engine services

Comment: I have set up `dispatch.yaml` and everything seems to be working fine. Unfortunately `api.example.com.*` and `www.api.example.com.*` returns an error, so I solved it in the way showned in the updated question. I think it is okay?

Comment: I have one more question, if I deploy both the Angular frontend and the Django backend in the Google App Engine, should I still set CORS as enabled in the Django settings as you mentioned in the answer? In some recommendations I found information to completely remove CORS configuration from the Django settings during deployment and now I have some doubts. Thank you in advance one more time!